# How many ways can a given Young tableau be written as part of the decomposition of tensor products of smaller ones?

Tags: representation-theory, young-tableaux

Given a representation in $SU(N)$ with Young tableau $Y$, how many ways are there that I can write $$Y \in y_1\otimes y_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes y_n$$ where $n\leq |Y|$, the number of boxes there are in $Y$ and $y_r$ are smaller Young tableaux, ie of sizes $\leq |Y|$? Here $n$ is not fixed.

Is there an explicit formula for that, or is it connected to something else? Any help is appreciated.

Let the function in question be $c(Y) $. Then
$c(\square) = 1$, $c\begin{pmatrix} \square \\\square \end{pmatrix} = 1 = c(\square\square) $, etc.

In fact I think I am interested in the weighted version, with the coefficient $N_{y_1,y_2,...,y_n} ^Y$ attached to the product $y_1\otimes y_2\otimes\cdots \otimes y_n$. Not sure how this is going to change the picture.

I mean I would like to find $$\sum _n \sum_{Y\in y_1\otimes \cdots \otimes y_n} N_{y_1,...,y_n} ^Y $$

Comment: Can you give an example to explain what exactly you mean here by the tensor product of tableaux? Generally tensor products of representations corresponding to a give. tableau decomposition as direct sums of other tableaux, rather than being a tableaux itself.

Comment: Yes, thats why I used $\in$ rather than $=$. i think it may be better to write the representation $Y$ belongs to part of the tensor product $y_1\otimes\cdots\otimes y_n = \cdots \oplus N_{y_1,...,y_n} ^Y Y \oplus \cdots$.

Comment: ah my bad! Totally missed that. Sorry

Comment: So the tensor product of the tableaux is actually the tensor product of representations of the tableaux.

Comment: You seem to be talking about the invariant parts of the $n$-fold tensor power of a representation. Is this correct? To see if this is right, write out $c(-)$ fior three boxes. Does it take values $1,2,1$?